# What libraries are included in the Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, androidx

When you google what the Android SDK is, it says one of the thing's the SDK contains are required libraries. What are these required libraries? Can you name a few? Are they all of the libraries I can find on the Android Documentation website?(AndroidX, Android support library, Android Platform, etc). 
So all libraries that are not on the website (butterknife, etc) are not apart of the SDK. My understanding is correct?

https://developer.android.com/reference/

Comment: It means all libraries to build a standard application on top of the Android device. It's excluding all the support libraries, ButterKnife, etc. You can build an application with the Android SDK alone, but without support libraries, your application (will) behave differently on each Android version.

Comment: but if you read another answer posted, he said that the android sdk does include the support library(android.support.* )? Or did i read that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
if you take a look at the SDK folder location you will find many different files that are responsible to build and develop an Android app using those specific setting of your SDK version.
To answer your question and name a few libraries it would be android.support.* the android support library. also before this was android.design library. And if you look at the latest its Android X 
All packages in AndroidX live in a consistent namespace starting with the string androidx. The Support Library packages have been mapped into the corresponding androidx.* packages

And yes your understanding is completely right in regards that butterknife ,piccaso,glide these all are third party libraries
In android sdk along with basic libraries there is implementaion of that particular version (Security and privacy) feature

Comment: Where are these "required libraries" though? Is it in the tools/lib folder? I see a lot of jar files, do these jar files contain all the classes/interfaces/etc?
Also my statement "Are they all of the libraries I can find on the Android Documentation website?" correct as well? 

You said " these all are third party libraries In android sdk along with basic libraries" So that means these 3rd party libraries are apart of the sdk? Why do we need to download them then? Sorry If my understanding is not correct.

Comment: 3rd party libraries are not the part of android sdk. these are there just to enhance and aidto the working abd feature of app development

Comment: hwn you start app development the basic library as per your target sdk are created and as you go on adding more library it gets downloadedi am not sure where it gets saved i would get back to you asap

Comment: yeah as per as jar files go yeah they have some classes and interface for your imolementation .Alo, in android sdk there is the basic sdk platform , then there are diffrent sdk tools such as google play, recyclerview,navbar,bottomnavigotion , these all are tool which can be downloadded if you use it in project

Comment: i will get back to you with detail if this aint clear enough

Comment: in android sdk there are 3 thinks first android sdk tools . which contain AVD , eulator, progaurd https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools   take a look

Comment: other are android build tools which contain and provide us with best upto date feature you can read about it here    https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools

Comment: apart from all that the sdk also contains the google repository